# How to get img src for image clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to get the img src for the specific image being clicked on. I am using the `this` function in my attempt, so I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Does anyone see the issue?

HTML:

```
<div id="zoomPop" data-popup="pop2">
    <div id="zoomInner">
        <a class="sharePopClose" data-popup-close="pop2" href="#"><img src="/icon_close.png" alt="Close Project Image" class="xClose">
        </a>
        <img src="" alt="Project Enlarge" id="zoomImg">
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
//Project Container Zoom
 $('#projectGallery').on('click', '.projectCont', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('#zoomPop').fadeIn(350);
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
  console.log(currentImg);
 });
```

```css
#zoomPop {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 color: #FFF;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999999;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 display: none;
}
#zoomPop {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
#zoomInner {
 position: relative;
 padding: 60px 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="projectGallery">
  <div class="projectCont">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2422/sky-earth-galaxy-universe.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Pic">
  </div>
  <div class="projectCont">
    <img src="https://geology.com/google-earth/google-earth.jpg" alt="Pic">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="zoomPop" data-popup="pop2">
  <div id="zoomInner">
    <img src="" alt="Project Enlarge" id="zoomImg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `this` refers to the `div.projectCont` in your context (inside the function), the div doesn't have a `src` attribute, try to get the `img` that is inside that div.

Comment: Try in that function `console.log(event.target.src)`

Comment: `'.projectCont'` -> `'.projectCont img'`

Comment: I'm not sure what else to do other than this. This didn't work. `var currentImg = $(this).find().closest('.projectCont img').attr('src');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `this` refer to DOM Node `<div class="projectCont">`
Use a

```
console.log($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
```

or change selector for event handler to

```
$('#projectGallery').on('click', '.projectCont img', function (event) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Project Container Zoom
 $('#projectGallery').on('click', '.projectCont img', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('#zoomPop').fadeIn(350);
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
  console.log(currentImg);
$('#zoomInner img').attr('src', currentImg);
 });
```

```css
#zoomPop {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 color: #FFF;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999999;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 display: none;
}
#zoomPop {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
#zoomInner {
 position: relative;
 padding: 60px 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="projectGallery">
  <div class="projectCont">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2422/sky-earth-galaxy-universe.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Pic">
  </div>
  <div class="projectCont">
    <img src="https://geology.com/google-earth/google-earth.jpg" alt="Pic">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="zoomPop" data-popup="pop2">
  <div id="zoomInner">
    <img src="" alt="Project Enlarge" id="zoomImg">
  </div>
</div>
```